# Return the first instance of image name string using regex expression

Tags: regex, shell, expression

I am trying to form a regex for below lines so that it returns the name of the image. I have multiple image formats.
The image formats that it has to return are jpg, png, PNG, jpeg, JPG.

For example, for the first line it should return me, the image's name -- `test-hire-logo.png`.
I've tried below regex , but it will only matches png type only.

```
([^\/]+)\.(png)
```

```
/content/dam/thesis/company-png/test-hire-logo.png.imgw.850.x.jpg
/content/dam/thesis/company/instance-hire-logo.jpg
/content/dam/thesis/company/testing hire.jpg
```

Comment: What about `([^\/]+)\.(png|jpg)` ?

Comment: this will return the complete match for the below case. 

`https://www.synopsys.com/content/dam/synopsys/solutions/cloud-white-paper-mockup-525x315.jpg.test.png`

It will match this in above: `cloud-white-paper-mockup-525x315.jpg.test.png` instead of image name i.e `cloud-white-paper-mockup-525x315.jpg``

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: It matches only the filename, see https://regex101.com/r/m8SHmo/1 But how are you using it?

Comment: I need the first .jpg part in the above example. I am using https://regexr.com/ website for validation and this is used for perl language.

Comment: If you use this with perl, then `.*\/\K[^\/\n]+?\.(?:png|jpg)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/fVKdE6/1

Comment: if you see this, [link] (https://regex101.com/r/piLtz9/1) it is returning the complete string, instead I just want the image name which is `cloud-white-paper-mockup-525x315.jpg`

Comment: Did you check the previous link?

Comment: Thank you so much, this really worked !! `.*\/\K[^\/\n]+?\.(?:png|jpg)\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PCRE for example, you can make use of `\K`

```
.*\/\K[^\/\n]+?\.(?:png|jpg)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `.*` Optionally match any character except newlines
- `\/\K` Match `/` then then forget what is matched so far
- `[^\/\n]+?` Match 1+ chars other than `/` or a newline, as few as possible (non greedy)
- `\.(?:png|jpg)` Match `.png` or `.jpg`
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVKdE6/1)

Or using a capture group (and if necessary not matching `/` until the end of the string)

```
^.*\/([^\/\n]+?\.(?:png|jpg))\b[^\n\/]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B5rb8D/1)

Note that if it is possible to use a different delimiter than `/` for the pattern, you don't have to escape the forward slash in the regex.